# mopub -- uploading an app image?

Tags: mopub

Trying to set up mopub for my game.

Still on their site and doing basic setup, but even that is so far going terribly. It does not seem that I am able to upload an app image. (Of course I did send them a message but I can't find any way to contact actual human support.) Every time I try, the loading image just spins and spins for what seems like forever. Is there a trick to it, is it borked, what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a reply -- looks like a mopub bug that they are working on...